# Internet Explorer alignment issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

When placing fixed with DIVs center by using margin:0 auto. It is ok in all browsers except IE. How to fix this issue for IE so that the div center aligns in IE.

Comment: I think "fixed with DIVs" should be "fixed width divs" - don't want to edit in case that's not true, can you confirm or edit yourself - and also I'll echo - Which IE version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean a "fixed width div"?

if so What's your Doctype?

in Quirks rendering mode IE will not centre a div with `margin: 0 auto;`

First I would suggest you change to a Strict Rendering Doctype, so you can avoid many of IE's other quirks, but if you absolutely can't do that, then the following should do it for IE.

```
body {text-align: center;}
div {width: 500px; text-align: left; margin: 0 auto; background: #eee;}

<body>
  <div>this div is in the center, even in IE Quirks Mode</div>
</body>
```

the `text-align: center` should be set on the parent element of the one you want to center, then reset the text-alignment how you want it to be on the actual element..

However I really would like to stress that if the cause is indeed a Quirks rendering Doctype that changing it (or adding one if you've not got one!) would be the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Pffff... after trying all of the above solutions I was still stuck with my DIV floating to the left. In ALL IE browsers.

My solution is this:

```
body { text-align: center;}
#content { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: left;}
```

and voila - it works!

And people, a good place to check how your work renders in all browsers is www.browserstack.com. Then you don't have to have this crappy IE *@/&%%$$(( browser installed!

Answer (score 0):

Define a fixed width to your element.

```
.myElement {
width:500px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Otherwise provide some code so we can see what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed width, you can use the following css:

```
#content {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   width: yourWidth;
   margin-left: - halfYourWidth;
}
```

Comment: Why making it absolutely positioned? It will just cause him additional issues later on.

Comment: Well I thought he has already set a fixed width to the divs thats why he would need to add some positioning, but you are quite right, `position: absolute` might not be the best solution (+1)

Comment: Yeah the question is horribly written :)